# Why is OnCollisonEnter2D not being called in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have 2 objects, one that moves down at a constant velocity and a player controlled object.  Both objects have BoxCollider2D and Rigidbody2D yet the OnCollisonEnter2D method attached to the controllable object isnt being called. Both the objects are colliding visibly colliding with each other and will rotate so long as freeze rotation is not on. Bellow is the code for the OnCollisonEnter2D method. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
```

public class Collisons : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Score;

```
public void OnCollisonEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    GameObject collider = collision.gameObject;
    Debug.Log("Collided");
    //checks to see if the block is correct;
    if (collider.GetComponent<BlockBehavior>().correct)
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        Score++;
    }
    else
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Movement>().gameOver = true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does both the objects in question have a RigidBody2D attached and does the gameobject with this script also have a Colider2D attached?

Comment: Yes they both have RigidBody2D's attached and they both have Box Collider2D's as well

Answer (score 0):

Check Z positions both GameObjects have to be on the same Z axis.

Comment: They are both on the same Z position. But one has a rect transform while the other just has a transform. Will that be a problem?

Comment: @RyanCooper One of the object is in canvas? If yes maybe it's Z position is not same as other object because it should be child of canvas, maybe you checking localPosition. Try to check both gameobject's worldPosition's Z are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your naming of the event is off. It should be **OnCollisionEnter2D**. Also, the parameters do not match.

it should be:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    GameObject collider = collision.gameObject;
    Debug.Log("Collided");
    //checks to see if the block is correct;
    if (collider.GetComponent<BlockBehavior>().correct)
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        Score++;
    }
    else
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Movement>().gameOver = true;
    }
}
```

I mark all these sort of events as private as **well** (convention), since it is not logic that you would want to expose to another script.

Comment: Good call on the naming convention. Unfortunately the method still is not being called.